# Hundreds of thousands hits from Asia coming from different IPs (not a crawler?)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache2

I have a prestashop web hosted on Digitalocean (ubuntu 18 / lamp) and since yesterday the server CPU an Memory is always at 100% even when my site don't have more than 300 visits a day.

I was tracking were the issue could be coming and after I ran goaccess on the apache logs I found out that just today the server was hitted 260K times from Asia (all of them coming from Android devices) and the hits are not to some specific urls but to thousands or actual pages from my site, and the hits doesn't appears to be from a known crawler (I've also check netstat and I see tons of `Foreign Address` ips…)

I don't know much about servers, can you please help me to understand what might be happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From your perspective the hits are effectively a denial of service.

There are a numberof things you cn do.  If you don't serve the Asian markets then you can block traffic based on the IP blocks (I have done this sucessfully myself when I have seen large numbers of unsolicited probes from certain networks, I have blocked the whole IP range).

Blocking can be done easily in Linux using iptables (or equivalent).

If you visit the IANA site you can access the lists of IP address blocks assigned, and if you can work out a pattern to the ones you wantto block then just block them.

So, for example, if you see a block x.y.0.0/16 (that's a big block) assigned to a foreign registry and lots of the traffic giving you a problem is coming from there, you can block with iptables like this:

```sh
iptables -I INPUT -s x.y.0.0/16 -j DROP
```

Making your site more resilient is also helpful.  Typically with a LAMP tyoe stack there is quite a lot of overhead with serving a page, making a connection to a database, processing scripts, possibly calls to external web services etc.  Even reasonably powerful servers can be overloaded quite easily.

Comment: Unfortunately, for you to block such traffic, it must first reach your network, using up bandwidth, thus achieving (to some degree) the DoS. Many business ISPs will work with you to block the traffic upstream of your network.

Comment: Yes, traffic must reach your network, but blocking in the kernel is highly efficient.  The data is not processed other than the headers being looked at for blocking.  And of course as you are blocking the SYN packets the attacker has no opportunity to send a payload to you.  So they can only send SYN packets which are small.  Typically in such scenarios if this is a co-ordinating attack the attacker moves in to a softer target.  However if they are specifically targetting your site (maybe a competitor) then they may change the attack vector ...

Comment: We have found it much easier and cleaner to just let the ISP block it in its network, and we simply do not need to worry about it, and we get the full use of the bandwidth we are paying for.

Comment: Thanks you both! I'm gonna write to Digital Ocean support to see if they can block them and if they can't (or don't want) I will block them using iptables.
Meanwhile: yesterday night I installed mod_security and today I'm not seeing more hits… could mod_security have done it or it is just that the "attack" has passed?